# WPVIP failing my JavaScript for using window.location

Tags: javascript, wordpress, xss, lint

Could someone explain how to correctly sanitise this line please?

`const url = new URL(window.location.href);`

I get the following error

> Data from JS global "window.location.href" may contain user-supplied values and should be sanitized before output to prevent XSS (WordPressVIPMinimum.JS.Window.location).

But can't find an answer online telling me *how* to sanitize the value

tried Google, tried reading docs, tried searching SO

---

Here's a little more code to show how the value is being used. Basically I'm updating some query params in the current URL when a user changes form elements

```
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    url.searchParams.set('sc', 123);
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, url.href)
```

Comment: _"I get the following error"_ - _is_ that an actual _error_ to begin with? Sounds more like a _hint_ some linter tool gave you. And what those have to say, is not always to be trusted blindly, or without checking whether it even applies in the current situation. _"should be sanitized before output"_ - does it _get_ "output" anywhere after this? What needs to be done, if anything, largely depends on what actually happens with the value, what it will get used for later one.

Comment: It's a linting error that unfortunately blocks me from releasing the code. I'll update the question with an example of how the value is being used.

Comment: Not sure what it wants you to do here, all the examples from https://docs.wpvip.com/technical-references/security/javascript-security-recommendations/ appear to apply to values that are getting introduced into the HTML context, but that isn't really the case here. Sure one could argue that by taking the given URL, replacing a parameter, and assigning that as the new location, values from the outside might get introduced - but that would rather have been the case on the page this code runs _on_ already then.